# Ember-data: store.query properly returns array but still throws error 'expecting array, found single record'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following express route for 'get all locations':

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){

    let q = req.query;

    let locations = Location.find({organization: q.organization});

    locations.then(r => res.status(200).send(r))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});
```

And this ember model hook triggers it correctly:

```
model(){
    return this.store.findRecord("user", this.get('session.currentUser.id'))
      .then(user => user.get('organization'))
      .then(org => this.store.query("location", {organization: org.id}))
}
```

Now, this query is sending a get request to the following url with params:

```
GET /locations?organization=571974742ce868d575b79d6a
```

And my server is returning a 200 success code but then the model hook is crashing with this error:

```
query to locations failed with error: Error: Assertion Failed: The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record. Please wrap your response in an array or use `store.queryRecord` to query for a single record.
```

Creating a postman request to the same address:

```
localhost:3200/locations?organization=571974742ce868d575b79d6a
```

I see an array returned, filled with the proper objects, like so:

```
[{object1}, {object2]
```

Which seems like the correct response. Why might Ember be telling me that it's only receiving a single record?

It even throws me this warning when the model hook is called:

```
WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "0" (resolved model name using lc-dash@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("0"))
```

**Edit:**

Realizing this may be a serializer/adapter error:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
    host: 'http://localhost:3200',
    authorizer: 'authorizer:application'
});
```

Maybe there is something missing from my serializer?

```
// app/serializers/application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({});
```

Comment: Which version of Ember Data? Which adapter / serializer are you using? (The default in Ember Data 2+ is the JsonApiAdapter / JsonApiSerializer, which is not compatible with your response).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Guarav I have edited the question to include my adapter and serializer code.

Comment: Also updating the project to 2.5.0 right now

Answer (score 7):

The RESTSerializer expects arrays of objects to be delivered inside a payload key matching the model name pluralized:

```
{
  "organizations": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key1": "value3",
      "key2": "value4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `JsonSerializer` if you would prefer not to send a payload key.

Comment: Renaming the file to match the name of the object seems to be the key here.

Comment: Either that or maybe:
```import Inflector from 'ember-inflector';
const inflector = Inflector.inflector;
inflector.uncountable('other_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, refer the following table to see whether server should return response in singular or plural.

`| Async from server/store | Sync from store      | Query server
Single Record | findRecord(type,id)     | peekRecord(type, id) | queryRecord(type, {query})
All Records   | findAll(type)           | peekAll(type)        | query(type, {query})`

Reference:

1.[CRUD with Ember (+ Data)](https://gist.github.com/pablobm/e77a98e5f3c610953a82)

2.[Ember_data_rest_api.md](https://gist.github.com/ldong/c52f491a88935a8c24337c1326586f99)